# c++ how to ? function_x ( new object1 )

Tags: c++, function, arguments, new-operator

Hi i want to do the next

instead of

```
MyClass object;
 function_x (object);
```

i want to

```
function_x ( new object );
```

so what will be the structure of the MyClass to be able to do that .. 
if i just compiled it , it gives me a compile time error

---

answer `function_x (MyClass() )`

New Edit thanks for the quick answers.. i did ask the wrong Question i should have asked how

temporary variables created in C++ and the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new` is called on classes, not objects. And it returns a pointer, so unless `function_x` accepts a pointer, this is impossible.

You can do this though:

```
void function_y(MyClass* ptr)
{
  // Do something
}

// Then call
function_y(new MyClass);
```

Note a few things about this:

1. The default constructor of `MyClass` is called when it's created
2. `function_y` must keep the pointer in some accessible place to avoid a memory leak

Is this what you need, or something else?

Comment: yes sorry i mistakenly wrote it  new object it should be 
new class 

but after another search i searched for something called ( temporary variables ) which what i needed in first place but couldn't be verbose (pardon my bad english )

so the temporary objects are something like:

function_x ( MyClass() ) 

directly and there is no new operator .. when i was programming in java we used  new MyClass

Comment: +1. You might want to add a little more about memory leaks, the concept of ownership and balancing `new` with `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

`new object` returns `object*`, so the signature for function_x should be:

```
void function_x(object* obj) {
}
```

And you can only call operator `new` on a class, not instances of a class.

Answer (score 0):

As per edit, if you want to create a temporary object you can like this:`function_x (MyClass ());` . Note that you can not modify this temporary object so your function_x should take this parameter by const-reference.